# Efficiently load and store data using Dask by changing one column at a time

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask

I'm in the process of implementing a csv parser using Dask and pandas dataframes. I'd like to make it load only the columns it needs, so it works well with and doesn't need to load large amounts of data.

Currently the only method I've found of writing a column to a parquet/Dask dataframe is by loading all the data as a pandas dataframe, modifying the column and converting from pandas.

```py
all_data = self.data_set.compute()              # Loads all data, compute to pandas dataframe
all_data[column] = column_data                  # Modifies one column
self.data_set = dd.from_pandas(all_data, npartitions=2) # Store all data into dask dataframe
```

This seems really inefficient, so I was looking for a way to avoid having to load all the data and perhaps modify one column at a time or write directly to parquet.

I've stripped away most of the [code](https://github.com/DCS77/data-analysis/blob/master/data-store/group.py) but here is an example function that is meant to normalise the data for just one column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

def normalise_column(self, column, normalise_type=NormaliseMethod.MEAN_STDDEV):
  column_data = self.data_set.compute()[column] # This also converts all data to pd dataframe
  
  if normalise_type is NormaliseMethod.MIN_MAX:
    [min, max] = [column_data.min(), column_data.max()]
    column_data = column_data.apply(lambda x: (x - min) * (max - min))

  elif normalise_type is NormaliseMethod.MEAN_STDDEV:
    [mean, std_dev] = [column_data.mean(), column_data.std()]
    column_data = column_data.apply(lambda x: (x - mean) / std_dev)

  all_data = self.data_set.compute()
  all_data[column] = column_data
  self.data_set = dd.from_pandas(all_data, npartitions=2)
```

Can someone please help me make this more efficient for large amounts of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the binary nature of the parquet format, and that compression is normally applied to the column chunks, it is never possible to update the values of a column in a file, without a full load-process-save cycle (the number of bytes would not stay constant). At least, Dask should enable you to do this partition-by-partition, without breaking memory.

It *would* be possible to make custom code to avoid parsing the compressed binary data in columns you know you don't want to change, just read and write again, but implementing this would take some work.